# How would I build an entire form using just json?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was given a little quiz to build out a form in html using only a json file using javascript.
Is that even possible just using js?
Can anyone provide me a link or something to reference on google to accomplish this task?
I have searched for "json file to html" but havent been able to find anything that could help thus far.
The json file contain a menu of items which can be ordered in quantity so I need to have form elements in there as well so as you can see its not an easy search.  Any tips or pointers would be great.
I have attached the json form so you can understand the task better.

```
{
    "menu": {
        "slice of pizza": "2.00",
        "toppings": {
            "pepperoni": ".25",
            "meatballs": ".35",
            "mushrooms": ".40",
            "olives": ".20"
        },
        "sides": {
            "potato salad": "1.25",
            "hummus": "2.50",
            "caesar salad": "3.50",
            "garden salad": "2.25"
        },
        "drinks": {
            "soda": {
                "small": "1.95",
                "medium": "2.20",
                "large": "2.50"
            },
            "juice": "2.00",
            "water": "1.25"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

correct me, you are gonna to achieve something like this ?

```
<h1>SLice of pizza: 2.00</h1>
<label>toping</label>
<select>
<option>peperoni .25</option>
...
<option>olive .20</option>
</select>
```

if you do so then all you need to do is looping through the json if has more than one valiue then you generate the select tag and then attach it to your html

i still dont post any code, i am afraid i catch your question wrong

Comment: Hi Ricky, the goal is to build the page out from the JSON information. Making it as dynamic as possible. So, for instance, if the restaurant owner added or removed menu items, the code would still work.

Comment: ok then you can use my answer previous logic let say you get the json through the api call and save the response in a variable, you have to loop the json if a key has value object then you build a selectbox